# Receive variable from a called batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, call, command-prompt

I have two batch file here, `test.bat` and `len.bat`.

`len.bat` is a function that receives input from `test.bat`, processes it and then return a result value back to `test.bat`.

**test.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
call len tesla
echo !result!
pause
```

**len.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "string=%~1"
for /l %%a in (0,1,10000) do if "!string:~%%a,1!" == "" (
    set result=%%a
    exit /b
)
```

When I open `test.bat`, I expect it would print a value. Instead, it says Echo is OFF.
There seem to be a problem passing the variable from `len.bat` to `test.bat`.

Comment: I suggest you read on the purpose of `setlocal`. So remove `delayedexpansion` from `len.bat`

Comment: I assume you know your length logic is massively inefficient.  For starters a string can **NEVER** be 10,000 bytes long in a batch file.  If you search the site you will find much more efficient code to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setlocal` can be thought of as a sandbox, and anything created inside of that sandbox exists for as long as the sandbox exists. The sandbox stops existing when `endlocal` is called - either explicitly, or implicitly when the script ends.

In `len.bat`, you add a sandbox inside of the sandbox with a second `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` command, and `!result!` is created inside of that inner sandbox. When `len.bat` ends, `!result!` is destroyed since it didn't exist before `len.bat` was called.

I suspect that you added the second `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` because you thought it was needed to use delayed expansion inside of `len.bat`, but delayed expansion is actually still enabled because it was turned on in `test.bat`.

**Delete the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` from `len.bat` and `test.bat` will correctly return "5".**

If you feel that you need to keep the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` in `len.bat` to use it separately from `test.bat`, you can explicitly call `endlocal` and chain the `set` command to it to trick the interpreter into letting the variable escape the sandbox.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "string=%~1"
for /l %%a in (0,1,10000) do if "!string:~%%a,1!" == "" (
    endlocal & set result=%%a
    exit /b
)
```

Comment: This works well if launched from batch file. But if I run `call len tesla` in cmd, that doesnt print anything, I tried setlocal a line before calling the function and it still doesn't work. Need help

Comment: @Darwish - `len.bat` doesn't have an `echo` command, so it will never print anything. The value gets stored in the variable `%result%`, so after the script ends, you can type `echo %result%` to get the string length. If you want to update the script to display the string length, just add `echo %%a` between the `endlocal` and `exit /b` lines.

Comment: Yes, after call len.bat i echo the variable from cmd. But it print !result! Other than the actual value. I even tried echo %result% and it still doesnt print the value.

Comment: [I can't replicate your problem.](https://imgur.com/hcwwSyD)

Comment: oh i see, i didn't put endlocal in len.bat

Answer (score 2):

Does this help you out? The string length is returned as `%ErrorLevel%`:

New **len.bat**

```sh
@Set "str=#%~1" & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@Set "len=0" & For /L %%G In (12,-1,0) Do @(Set /A "len |= 1 << %%G"
    For %%H In (!len!) Do @If "!str:~%%H,1!" == "" Set /A "len &= ~ 1 << %%G")
@EndLocal & Exit /B %len%
```

Example **test.bat**

```sh
@Call "len.bat" four
@Echo %ErrorLevel% & Pause
@Call "len.bat" "nineteen inc spaces"
@Echo %ErrorLevel% & Pause
```

Comment: whats the difference between @set and set

Comment: `@set` is to `set`, what `@call` is to `call` and `@echo` is to `echo`. Open a Command Prompt window, and run `test.bat` from there, after removing randomly some of the `@` characters form wither one of the batch files to see what they do! `@` prevents the command line/block from being printed to the screen. Many people use the line `echo off` to do that for everything in the script, and prefix it with `@` to prevent `echo off` being printed to the screen at the time it is run.

Comment: It's up to you whether you with to have a line at the top `@Echo Off`, and remove all of the other five `@` characters, but for me especially as `len.bat` doesn't need modification and is never run on its own, as it's a helper script, that would just add six bytes of unnecessary size to the script. `@Echo Off` plus a carriage return and line feed pair is eleven characters/bytes, whereas five `@` characters uses only five bytes!